# How to include validate/validate.proto file?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a proto file called `user.proto` like following

```
syntax = "proto3";

package user;

import "validate/validate.proto";

option go_package = "pkg/proto/user";

message User {
    required string id = 1;
    required string name = 2 [
        (validate.rules).string.min_len = 2,
        (validate.rules).string.max_len = 50
    ];
}
```

I am using `validate/validate.proto` file as mentioned in the official docs [**here**](https://github.com/bufbuild/protoc-gen-validate/tree/main#build-from-source) but I seems to get import error like

```
validate/validate.proto: File not found.
user.proto:5:1: Import "validate/validate.proto" was not found or had errors.
```

My proto file dir structure is

```
proto
├── auth
│   └── auth.proto
├── common
│   └── common.proto
└── user
    └── user.proto
```

and the command I am using to build the proto is the following

```
protoc --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=. --validate_out="lang=go:." user.proto
```

How can I import this??

Comment: Please (a) include the command that you're using to compile the proto file that's generating the error; (b) show your folder structure (`user.proto` and `validate/validate.proto`. You will need to ensure that `validate/validate.proto` is on the `proto_path`.

Comment: @DazWilkin added the details. I think I need to have validate.proto and include that in my path while building but vscode still would give error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for updating the question!

Assuming this structure:

```
.
├── bufbuild
│   └── validate
│       └── validate.proto
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── pkg
│   └── proto
│       └── user
│           ├── user.pb.go
│           └── user.pb.validate.go
└── proto
    ├── auth
    ├── common
    └── user
        └── user.proto
```

I've put `bufbuild/validate/validate.proto` locally (`${PWD}`) to demonstrate the use but this likely exists in your clone of the `bufbuild` repo and the path to it should reflect that location.

Here's the solution:

1. Remove the `required` statements; these aren't supported by `proto3`

`user.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package user;

import "validate/validate.proto";

option go_package = "pkg/proto/user";

message User {
    string id = 1;
    string name = 2 [
        (validate.rules).string.min_len = 2,
        (validate.rules).string.max_len = 50
    ];
}
```

2. `protoc` is **very** particular about paths:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD}/proto \
--proto_path=${PWD}/bufbuild \
--go_out=${PWD} \
--go-grpc_out=${PWD} \
--validate_out="lang=go:${PWD}" \
${PWD}/proto/user/user.proto
```

- I've used `${PWD}` as it's more evident than `.` but the two forms are interchangeable.
- The first occurrence of `proto_path` roots on your `proto` directory. The effect of this is that `protoc` effectively ignores this absolutel (!) path (i.e. the value of `${PWD}`) when it looks for the tree of protobuf sources.
- `user.proto` is in `package user;` and this means that `protoc` expects to find in one of its `proto_path`'s (i.e. this one) in a folder called `user` (i.e. `${PWD}/proto`+`/`+`user`).
- The second occurrence of `proto_path` roots on the `bufbuild` repo. The effect of
- `validate.proto` is in `package validate;` and this means that `protoc` expects to find it in one of its `proto_path`'s (i.e. this one) in a folder called `validate` (i.e. `${PWD}/bufbuild`+`/`+`validate`.
- Even though `proto_path` has been specified, **all** references to protobuf sources must still include the full path (and, of course, this must match one of the `proto_path`'s) so we must `${PWD}/user`+`/`+`user.proto`

Comment: Thanks for answering, I was wondering, (1) How vscode would stop complaining about `validate.proto` not found and (2) From where I should get the `validate.proto` file?

Comment: It's included with the `protoc-gen-validate` repo [`validate.proto`](https://github.com/bufbuild/protoc-gen-validate/blob/main/validate/validate.proto)